# EPS8266 writing number to EEPROM fails to write, returns 0

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, eeprom

I am using an ESP8266 and trying to write to the EEPROM. My goal is to save an array of 4 digit numbers (2 byte ints), but here I made a test for one number. The serial monitor output is "0" for number2. can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

int number1 = 1010;
Serial.println(number1);
      EEPROM.write(0, number1 >> 8);
      EEPROM.write(1, number1 & 0xFF);
      EEPROM.commit();

      int number2 = (EEPROM.read(0) << 8) + EEPROM.read(1);

Serial.println(number2);

}
void loop() {}
```

Comment: EEPROM.begin() is missing. https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom

Comment: if it was a snake... thank you